# Where does external device logic belong in domain driven design?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I am attempting to develop a new project from a more domain driven perspective and whilst I mostly understand the principles a few things still allude me.

My domain requires interaction with external devices and therefore I need to define interfaces for device discovery, model creation and to an extent communication.

Does stuff like the above belong in the core domain, or from a domain driven perspective does stuff like this (which aids my domain but is not my domain per se) sit outside the domain entirely and use the behaviour defined within the domain to do work?

To add a little more information, I currently have the architecture modelled similar to as follows:

```
* Domain (references nothing)
  + IDiscoverDevices (device discovery interface)
    - BeginDiscovery: void
    - EndDiscovery: void
  + IDeviceProvider (factory for device creation)
    - Make: IDevice
  + IDevice

* Framework (references Domain)
  + DiscoverDevices
  + DeviceProvider

* Client (references Domain and Framework)
  + SomeView (takes IDiscoverDevices, IDeviceProvider via ctor)
```

Comment: We are debating the use of DDD in a similar context. We're leaning towards not using DDD since we fail to see the real business logic in our case. We are merely providing the glue that connects the devices, which could probably be considered business logic.

Comment: @ChristopheHerreman - I am beginning to come to a similar conclusion regarding the use of DDD and honestly my more recent development has been less than domain driven.  Further research into the use and benefits of DDD suggest it is not as useful in a context where there is more technical logic than business logic such is my project.

Comment: It would be great if ppl would stop thinking of DDD as yet another hammer. DDD is a mindset, when you try to model things and to identify _if_ you have a Domain you are using DDD. If your app is just a component gluing things, anything that models concepts required by it, structure and behaviour, is your Domain.

Comment: @ Christophe Herreman Your domain is your whole problem space and those can be virtually anything, from modeling chips and circuits to data tracking. Sometimes, transaction scripts or CRUD fits the deal better, but a form of ubiquitous language can still be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html), your interfaces would be defined in the domain, but they would be implemented in the infrastructure layer.

Answer (score 0):

If it aids your domain but is not part of your domain per se it is not part of the core domain but part of a supporting subdomain.
Different subdomains should usually be modeled in seperate bounded contexts. So you should have at least two models: one for your
core domain and one for your supporting subdomain (the external device logic).

The context of the external device logic should be integrated in the 
context of your core domain using some translation layer, for example using an Anti Corruption Layer. Note, the Anti Corruption Layer is part of
the core domain context and therefore it should abstract the model of the external devices in the language of the core domain.

This is of cause not a general solution but assumes that Domain Driven Design is really applicable for your problem, i.e. your core domain is complex with a lot of business rules which provides competetive advantage to your business. If this is not the case you should not use DDD but use something simpler, e.g. using the Dependency Inversion Principle like plalx suggested in his answer.